# Recursively find minimum and maximum values in an array

Tags: c++, recursion

Attaching what I've done; having a problem that the recursion sticks on the left recursive calls and can't continue to the right recursive calls. can't figure out how to return the recursion to the first position and continue the program to run towards the right recursive calls.

```
void minMax(int A[], int left, int right, int &min, int &max)
{
    if (right == 0)
        return;
    if (A[(left + right) / 2] <= min)
        min = A[(left + right) / 2];
    if (A[((left + right) / 2)] >= max)
        max = A[((left + right) / 2)];
    if (right > 0)
        minMax(A, left, (right - left) / 2, min, max);
    if(left < right)
        minMax(A, (right - left) / 2, right, min, max);

}
```

Comment: It seems to me that you are overcomplicating, or i don't understand what you want. So, minMax is working like this: from{3, 5, 17, 4, 2,5} the min should be 2, the max should be 17, not?

Comment: yes, I know there's a simpler solution. though I would like to solve it recursively and using the binary search pattern.

Comment: No, there is a simpler recursive function. I'll write it and if you want, use it.

Comment: @Lasoloz ok I appreciate it

Comment: It's an assignment, to write it with binary search pattern?

Comment: @Lasoloz that's true.

Comment: On wikipedia you can find a code example, try using that. I can't help you more, because I'm on mobile phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Similar** approach as the merge sort :

Here is the recursive solution in C :
*a* is your array, *i* and *j* your left and right ...

```
void minmax (int* a, int i, int j, int* min, int* max) {
int lmin, lmax, rmin, rmax, mid;
if (i == j) {
*min = a[i];
*max = a[j];
} else if (j == i + 1) {
if (a[i] > a[j]) {
  *min = a[j];
  *max = a[i];
} else {
  *min = a[i];
  *max = a[j];
}
} else {
mid = (i + j) / 2;
minmax(a, i, mid, &lmin, &lmax);
minmax(a, mid + 1, j, &rmin, &rmax);
*min = (lmin > rmin) ? rmin : lmin;
*max = (lmax > rmax) ? lmax : rmax;
}

}
```

Although there are a lot of different and easier solutions ...

**Edit by Question asker:** ...because the question was about C++ program, this would be the C++ version

```
void minMax(int a[], int left, int right, int &min, int& max) {
    int lmin, lmax, rmin, rmax, mid;
    if (left == right)
    {
        min = a[left];
        max = a[right];
    }
    else if (right == left + 1)
    {
        if (a[left] > a[right])
        {
            min = a[right];
            max = a[left];
        }
        else
        {
            min = a[left];
            max = a[right];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        mid = (left + right) / 2;
        minMax(a, left, mid, lmin, lmax);
        minMax(a, mid + 1, right, rmin, rmax);

        if (lmin > rmin)
            min = rmin;
        else
            min = lmin;
        if (lmax > rmax)
            max = lmax;
        else
            max = rmax;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler recursion is:

```
void minMax(int& A[], int index, const int& lenght, int& min, int& max)
{
if (A[index] < min) min = A[index]);
else if (A[index] > max) max= A [index];

if (++index < lenght) minMax(A, index, lenght, min, max);
}
```

In this case you just iterate through recursively, and not left-right.